# iOS - Require iOS 13+

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

In my flutter application, it uses "Sign in with Apple", which requires iOS 13. Is there a way to require iOS 13+ on the app store? I do not want non-iOS 13+ users downloading it as they will not be able to login.

Comment: You project settings has a "iOS Deployment Target" where you can specify the minimum supported "target"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is determined from the xcode before uploading the compilation to the store, you must select in version iOS 13 in target

[image]

[image]